# Hypothetical Buoyancy Correction

Tags: mass, buoyancy

I have a hypothetical question about buoyancy corrections. The equation for a buoyancy correction is found on this website: https://www.vcalc.com/wiki/Dasha/Buoyancy+Equation

Imagine that you have a cup with a lid made out of a material (plastic, aluminum, etc.). You use a balance and weigh the lid and the cup simultaneously on the balance and record the mass. You can find the true mass using the buoyancy correction above as you know the density of the material.

Subsequently you seal the cup with the lid with the atmosphere inside. This seal is perfect and no air can escape or enter. Essentially, you have significantly changed the density of your object now (for example, it would float now). If you were to weigh the cup, would the observed mass change?

Logically it seems to me that the observed mass would not change as you aren't really weighing anymore mass and the pressure inside the container is the same as the atmospheric pressure. However, according to the equation above the observed mass should change slightly when you do the buoyancy correction. Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The calculated true mass will be different, and this is correct.

If you use the density of the cup material, you are calculating the mass of cup that you have. However, if you use the average density of the closed cup containing air, then you are calculating the mass of the cup plus the mass of the air contained within.

You should find, therefore, that if you use the lower density of the closed cup in the calculation, you get a slightly larger answer by an amout (density of air) x (volume of cup).